# Parse specific XML format to dataframe in R

Tags: r, xml, parsing

I receive several customer tables in xml format from an application and would like to load them in a data frame. It is obviously a somewhat unusual XML file, as the individual customer information is not supplied as a single attribute.
Here is an example file with 3 data sets. The original file has about 50 fields per customer and a total of 50,000 data records.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<document name="20220930_customer.xml" date="2022-09-30">
<customers ID="1" Name="customer A" currency="EUR"/>
<customers ID="2" Name="customer B" currency="USD"/>
<customers ID="3" Name="customer C" currency="EUR"/>
</document>
```

As a result I would like to extract the following dataframe:

```
 ID       Name currency
  1 customer A      EUR
  2 customer B      USD
  3 customer C      EUR
```

with the `xml` and the `xml2` library with `xmlToDataFrame()` I unfortunately get the following error message:

```
Error in matrix(vals, length(nfields), byrow = TRUE) :
  'data' must be of a vector type, which is 'NULL'
```

Does anyone have a tip on how I can parse the datasets and convert them into a dataframe?

Answer (score 0):

`xmlToDataFrame()` is meant to deal with xml elements, and not with xml attributes.

You could read attributes manually With `xml2`:

```
library(xml2)

doc <- xml2::read_xml('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<document name="20220930_customer.xml" date="2022-09-30">
<customers ID="1" Name="customer A" currency="EUR"/>
<customers ID="2" Name="customer B" currency="USD"/>
<customers ID="3" Name="customer C" currency="EUR"/>
</document>')

children <- xml_children(doc)

data.frame(ID=xml_attr(children,"ID"),
           Name=xml_attr(children,"Name"),
           currency=xml_attr(children,"currency")
           )

  ID       Name currency
1  1 customer A      EUR
2  2 customer B      USD
3  3 customer C      EUR
```